# Выполнить JavaScript после выполнения Yandex Metrika и прочих пикселей и счётчиков

Tags: javascript, dom, google-analytics, counter

Как выполнить некий JS код, скажем `alert()` только после того как DOM загружен, `$(document).ready()`, `$(window).load()`, и все остальные js в браузере выполнены (!), включая различные счетчики google analytics, yandex metrika, facebook pixel и т.п. Понятно, что у них у всех используются async или defer.

Comment: Возможно будет полезно [Document.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)

Comment: @MishaSaidov а он разве JS учитывает? Вроде только CSS и HTML

Comment: `Учитывает состояние загрузки страницы`. Сюда входят все подгружаемые ресурсы.

Comment: Учтите, разница между все js ресурсы **загружены**  или **выполнены** - существенная! Вы что именно хотите?

Comment: Выполнить. К примеру должны отработать счётчики, а после уже выполнить что-то